# generating *char buffer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to create a buffer that contains 300 symbols and pass it to the function described below:

```
void printThis(char *info);
```

What is the best way to generate this buffer?

If this is good:

```
char *buffer = new char()
```

then, how to add characters to this buffer? The following method is not good and it raises an access violation:

```
for (int i=0; i<300;i++)
{
   sprintf(s,"%s",'a');
}
```

Comment: Because `%s` expects a `char *`, and `'a'` is a char. Also, if you do this, you should really replace `s` with `s + i` - `sprintf()` has no way to know where it finished printing - it isn't `strcat()` that starts from the terminating nul...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<char> buffer(300, 'a');

// I'm guessing that printThis wants a zero-terminated string
buffer.push_back(0);

printThis(&buffer[0]);
```

If you're using the C++11 library, then `buffer.data()` might look nicer than `&buffer[0]`.

If you really want to manage the memory yourself (hint: you don't), either create an automatic array:

```
char buffer[300];
```

or a dynamic array:

```
char * buffer = new char[300];

// Don't forget to delete it, and hope than nothing threw an exception
delete [] buffer;
```

Comment: Or `std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[300]);` instead of `new` and `delete`.

Answer (score 0):

> if this is good:

It isn't. It really, really, isn't. It's not even a buffer. Nor is this even close to a good idea.

```
std::string s;
for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    s.push_back('a'); // good job all round
std::cout << s; // 300*a. Why? Who knows?
printThis(s.c_str());
```

Comment: In this case, `std::string s(300, 'a');`